# F# Query Expressions: cannot use "for"!

Tags: for-loop, f#, query-expressions

For whatever reason, I cannot use a "for" construct within a query expression. What I get is the following error. The code I just what I picked that used to work -->
"error: This control construct may only be used if the computation expression builder defines a 'For' method"

```
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"

open FSharp.Linq
open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

[<Literal>]
let connectionString' = @"
    data source = ...;
    initial catalog = NORTHWND;
    Integrated Security = SSPI"

type NorthwndDb =
    SqlDataConnection<connectionString', Pluralize = true>

let db' = NorthwndDb.GetDataContext()

let curstomerSortedByCountry =
    query { for c in db'.Customers do
                sortBy c.Country
                select (c.Country, c.CompanyName) } 
    |> Seq.cache
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this occurs in one script and not in another.

Answer (score 8):

I was not able to test this with your code snippet (don't have a database to test this against), but I think the kind of error you are reporting would happen if you defined a variable named `query` somewhere in your code snippet before the `query` expression. For example:

```
let query = "oops!"
let curstomerSortedByCountry =
    query { for c in [1 .. 10] do
            sortBy c
            select c }
```

> error FS0708: This control construct may only be used if the computation expression builder defines a 'For' method

The reason for this is that the identifier `query` in `query { .. }` is just a variable declared in the standard F# library that has various members including `query.For`. If you hide this with your own declaration, then the member will not be found.

Comment: Thank you Tomas, for this and for all your hard work promoting the language and answering questions, etc. Yes, that was the problem. BTW, is there such a tool in works that would translate an SQL Query to an F# Query Expression?

Comment: I'm happy I could help - I don't think there is a SQL -> F# Query tool - there is probably not a high demand for that.